# Sending an error to the subscription RXJS

Tags: error-handling, rxjs

I created a function that is supposed to catch error:

```
private pipeError(): any {
 return catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>): 
                    HttpErrorResponse | any => {
 if (error.status === 400 || error.status === 402) {
    return Observable.throw(error);  
 } else if (error.status === 401) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return Observable.throw(error);
   }
 });
}
```

Then I created a function that should send a query to api:

```
private post(path: string, data: Object, headers: HttpHeaders = this.getHeaders()): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}${path}`, data, { headers }).pipe(
      this.pipeError(),
      map((response: Object): Object | any => {
        if (response instanceof Object) {
          return response;
        } else {
          return empty();
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

And in order to call the function above, I create a new function in which it passes appropriate paramaters:

```
userRegister(data: UserRegisterInterface): Observable<Object> {
    return this.post('accounts/register/', data);
  }
```

OTHER COMPONENT:
And now in another component you subscribe to this function

```
this.createAccountSubscription = this.api.userRegister(datadata).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I wanted my pipeError function to return to this error subscription, but this does not work, it does:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yVEE.png)

Comment: Your `pipeError` doesn't always return an Observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not always handling the error. I think you could rewrite `pipeError()` like this:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

private pipeError(): any {
    return catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>):
        HttpErrorResponse | any => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }

        return throwError(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Still error:
`TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Observable.throw is not function`